# Proving induction for the rationals

Tags: group-theory

[image]

I have stumbled across this question and I have completed parts a) (i) (ii) and (iii) but I am stuck on (iv).

I know to extend induction to the rationals I need to prove 4 things, one of which is that ${p(x) \implies p(-x)}$ but I am unsure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is a group homomorphism, we have $\forall q\in\mathbb Q,\;f(-q)=-f(q)$ and $\forall a\in\mathbb N,\;\forall q \in \mathbb Q,\; f(aq)=f(q+\dots+q)=f(q)+\dots+f(q) = a f(q)$.

Now, if $q=\pm\dfrac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb N$, then
$$f(q)=f\left(\pm\dfrac ab\right) =a f\left(\pm\dfrac 1b\right) =\pm a f\left(\dfrac 1b\right)=\pm \dfrac ab f(1)=f(1)q.$$

Comment: This is a general property of group morphisms. Here, $\forall q\in\mathbb Q, \; 0 = f(0) = f(q+(-q)) = f(q)+f(-q)$ so $f(-q)=-f(q)$.